# iOS fastlane deliver lane issue - Invalid code signing entitlements

Tags: fastlane, code-signing-entitlements

We are trying to integrate Appdome into our product, we are facing the below issue via Fastlane scripts - deliver lane while uploading to transporter.

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/MobileCardServices.app/MobileCardServices' is not supported."

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can delete current provisioning profiles and regenerate them as mentioned here:


https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/12758